# Inductive Proof Confusion

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm learning inductive proofs in one of my computer science classes.  Our homework was graded and this was one of the solutions.  I understand all of it except for one line.  If anyone could break down how the marked line in the induction step was derived, that would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

```
5 divides (6^n − 1)

Proof

Base case: When n = 0, (6^n − 1) becomes (6^(0) − 1) = 0. We have 5 divides 0, because 0=5×0. Thus, 5 divides(6^n−1) when n=0.

Induction step: Let n be an arbitrary natural number larger than or equal 0. Assume 5 divides (6^n − 1). We will prove that 5 divides (6^n+1 − 1). Since 5 divides (6^n − 1), there exists an integer x such that 6^n − 1 = 5x. Then we have
         6^n+1 −1 = 6^n × 6 − 1 
                  = 6^n × 5 + 6^n −1 <------------ // THIS LINE
                  = 6^n × 5 + 5x (by the inductive assumption) 
                  = 5(6^n + x)
Since both 6n and x are integers, so is the sum (6^n +x). Thus 6^n+1 −1 equals 5 multiplied with an integer, which means 5 divides 6^n+1 − 1. By induction, we have 5 divides (6^n − 1) for all natural integers n ≥ 0.
```

Comment: Too many things in your question jut don't make any sense. $5$ does not divide $6n-1$ for every integer value of $n$. When $n=0$, $(6n − 1)$ **does not** become $(60 − 1)$, and $60-1$ is most certainly not equal to $0$.

Comment: Sorry, this was an error that occurred during the copy and paste.  Some of the fonts didn't convert correctly.  I will fix.

Comment: It was very late where I'm at when I posted and I didn't realize that the exponential notation didn't show up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $$6n\times 6-1=6n\times (5+1)-1=6n\times 5+6n\times 1-1=6n\times 5+6n-1.$$ The second equality is just the distributive law: $A\times (B+C)=A\times B+A\times C$.

This might be easier to see if we first ignore the "$-1$":

$$6n\times 6=6n\times (5+1)=6n\times 5+6n\times 1=6n\times 5+6n.$$

Note the order of operations: "$\times$" binds more tightly than "$+$," so e.g. "$A\times B+C\times D$" means "$(A\times B)+(C\times D)$," not "$A\times (B+C)\times D$".

Comment: Ok, this makes total sense.  I understand all of this when certain in-between steps aren't skipped, but it really throws me for a loop when they are.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as the system lets me.  Thanks.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Glad to help! FWIW, when I was learning this stuff and saw an step "$A=B$" that I didn't understand, I found it useful to try analyzing "$A-B$" - usually, for whatever reason, it's easier to pick that apart and eventually see that it all cancels out, than it is to see the equality itself. For instance, here we'd have $((6n\times 6)-1)-(6n\times 5+6n-1)=6n\times 6-1-6n\times 5-6n+1$. The $-1$ and $+1$ cancel, so we're left with $6n\times 6-6n\times 5-6n$; factor out the $6n$, and this is just $0$.

Comment: Hey Noah, I made a silly mistake.  When copying and pasting the text, the exponential notation didn't copy over, so my entire problem was copied over entirely wrong.  I've corrected the question and I think your answer still holds true, but I'm not entirely sure.  Basically ever 6n should've been a 6^n.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Yes, the answer is still the same - all that we used was $A\times 6=A\times 5+A$.